SnapSDK Creative Kit problem with startSending(content)
In Swift project there is installed package SnapSDK SPM, and info file configured with clientid. I am trying to use SCSDKSnapAPI.startSending() for sharing image from app to Snapchat. This successfully opens Snapchat, but no content is transmitted and Snapchat shows error (alert box):

Something went wrong. Please try again later.

This is code where share is initiated:
import SCSDKCreativeKit

struct shareView: View {
    @State private var snapAPI = SCSDKSnapAPI()
...

    var body: some View {
...
        Button {
            let snap = SCSDKSnapPhoto(image: image)
            let snapContent = SCSDKPhotoSnapContent(snapPhoto: snap)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                snapAPI.startSending(content) {
                    res in
                    print(res)
                }
            }
        }
   }
}

Result of startSending function is nil, meaning no error occurred.
I have checked bundleid on snap developer portal and clientid in info file. I have defined SCSDKSnapAPI object as state field of parent struct so it's on struct level scope and not on function level.
Any thoughts on this are welcome!

I had issues, until I added Test Users into kit.snapchat.com, under the app details, below API Tokens. Hope that helps?
